# Expected value of a minimum of 2 random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, expected-value

I have two independent (but not necessarily identically distributed) random variables: $X>0, Y>0$. All of their moments are known but we don't know the distributions.

Can we find an upper bound for $E[min(X,Y)]$ that is better than $min(E[X],E[Y])$ with the information given without knowing the distributions?

Comment: You can get the proper font and spacing for $\min$ using `\min`. For operators that don't have a command of their own, you can use `\operatorname{name}`.